# How to change this guitar overdrive schematic to use lower supply voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I'm trying to redesign this schematic (from [here](https://www.wamplerpedals.com/blog/uncategorized/2020/05/how-to-design-a-basic-overdrive-pedal-circuit/)) in order to be able to use a lower supply voltage of 3.7V (Li-Ion battery) with a 0~5V-supplied modern op-amp (e.g. [TLC2272](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiSpOSfw67_AhU0RPEDHbyzCKoQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2FTLC2272&usg=AOvVaw2Rt-uIfzn8eHbr6y1XtYyZ) from ti). The schematic here and the op-amp used, obviously use higher voltage of 9V:

[image: Basic overdrive from Wampler]

I'm quite newbie on analog electronics but I guess these steps should be taken:

- **The RC values for filters should stay the same** since the voltage has nothing to do with the RC filter values.
- **Any bias applied to a "constant voltage element" (my term) like a BJT or diode, should be recalculated** to maintain it with the new supply
- Op-amp input bias of Vcc/2 should be the same on the new one.
- All proportional voltage points which are a fraction of the supply voltage, stay the same until they are connected to a "constant voltage element" like a diode or a BJT.

So according to these steps most of circuit stays unchanged. However, I'm not sure if the 2 diodes are happy with the new supply since they are somehow a "constant voltage element".
Do the overdrive functionality still work with just changing the op-amp?

Comment: Datasheet of TLC2272 says two things that don't seem appropriate 1) Supply voltage min is ±2.2V, so you'd need at least a 4.4V battery voltage 2) Input voltage ranges from VDD- to VDD+ - 1.5V. Given that you input is biased at VBAT / 2 = 3.7V / 2 = 1.85V, it means the peak input cannot exceed 3.7 - 1.5 - 1.85 = 0.35V. I don't know what the level is for you guitar signal, but that seems pretty low.

Comment: I think you're going to get harder clipping as the headroom is lesser with 3.7V supply. It'll become more like a fuzz pedal instead of an overdrive pedal. Simulate it with LT spice and take a look at the output. I don't think any changes have to be made to the circuit as the op amp raises the voltage untill it is clipped by the diode.

Comment: Not sure if the TL082 can give you enough headroom,  switch to a rail to rail opamp

Comment: The 3.7V battery voltage drops to 3V or a little less for each use. If you find an opamp that works from a supply that low then its input will need voltage protection.

Comment: @Audioguru you mean the spikes from a passive pickup would get higher than 3V ?

Comment: @dim Yeah I think I chose the wrong one. I think a 2.7V to 5V supply, rail-to-rail op-amp should work then. right?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad yes, and to ensure enough headroom for the signal, choose a RRIO opamp (rail to rail on both input and output).

Comment: An electric guitar magnetic pickup usually has a preamp powered from 9V and has no gain or a low gain and can produce up to 6V. A piezo pickup can produce hundreds of volts if it is hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Do the overdrive functionality still work with just changing the
> op-amp?*

Yes this will remain good for the new circuit\$^1\$ however, if you are changing the op-amp to a device that can work on the proposed low voltage supply, do yourself a favour and pick an op-amp that can also tolerate the original supply voltage. Then, it gives you the ability to compare performance at the original voltage and the new lower supply voltage.

Regarding the tone control, add a 470 Ω resistor between C3 and the left connection of the 10 kΩ potentiometer to avoid the op-amp becoming unstable when the pot is would fully to its left side.

Also add a 100 nF capacitor directly across the power pins of the op-amp.

---

\$^1\$ as dim pointed out in a comment below your question, the device you have chosen is inappropriate for working on a 3.7 volt lithium battery because its lowest recommended supply is 4.4 volts. Choose an op-amp that can work from a single rail of 2.7 volts to at least 10 volts.